# what are small size, large size image url and subtitle in iOS ad hoc distribution?

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning, ad-hoc-distribution

Its being long time i am creating `iOS Ad-Hoc builds` to distribute application to limited people. I always leave `Subtitle`, `Large Image Size` and `Small Image Size` blank because these are optional.

Can anybody describe me what is use of these options? Or where does really these thing will appear if I create a Ad-Hoc version?

Thank you...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Creating **.ipa** file when you Share this to `Distribute for Enterprise` it Shows

[image]

where,

**Subtitle:** `typically company name`.

**Large Image Size:** the large 512×512 icon used by iTunes.

**Small Image Size:**
display-image: the icon to display during download.

Comment: whats role of `iTunes` for `Large Image Size`?

Comment: Its just Icon image for app.

Comment: you are right. I can see 57x57 icon during install. What about Subtitle? where that title shoul appear?